# how to increase the security of my callable cloud function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I want to make a search feature on my mobile app for my Firestore database, so I will use Elastic Search product (Swiftype), if I make more search requests then it will be more expensive (it is around 100.000 requests/ $10, the data will be transfered through their restful API

I am worried that will be a malicious user that can make thousands of requests in short period of time and it will ruin my billing. so, to make it safe and avoid malicious user then I make a callable cloud function like this because I also use Firebase Authentication on my mobile app

```
exports.performFullTextSearch = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    if (context.auth) {

        // make request to Elastic Search

    } else {
 
        // perform rejection
    }

})
```

is it safe to prevent malicious users by using the code above ? can I improve the security ? I am sorry I am actually an Android and iOS developer. so I have limited knowledge about backend

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your code is correct to avoid any authenticated user to run the Elastic Search. Just end the Cloud Function with `return null;` as follows.

```
exports.performFullTextSearch = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    if (context.auth) {

        // make request to Elastic Search

    } else {
        return null;
    }

})
```

---

To be complete, note that a non authenticated user will be able to call the Cloud Function (resulting in one Cloud Function invocation) but will not be able to run the code in the first part of the `if` block.

Comment: @sarah I see you have un-accepted the answer. Is there any specific reason? If you need more help or more details around my answer, do not hesitate to contact me, in such a way we find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, nothing can be said safe...

If you are really tensed for the number of requests, there can be a workaround by which you can impose a limit on *number of requests by a **user** in a certain period (which should be enough for **normal users***).

So let's say if you allow only **5** requests to be made in **10 minute**. You store a boolean variable in your database:

```
boolean isLimitExceeded;
```

which tells if the limit of the user is exceeded or not, which you have to update accordingly. In your function, you check if the limit is exceeded or not and accordingly give a result:

```
if(isLimitExceeded){
    //reject
} else {
   //perform the search
}
```

Obviously, this would increase your costs of Firebase Firestore Database, but something needs to be compromised!

You can store this in the local device too, but of course, you cannot say when the user clears the data.

### Update

The final code which should be implemented is:

```
if (context.auth) {

    if(isLimitExceeded){

       // limit is exceeded, reject

    } else {

      //limit not exceeded and the user is authenticated perform the search

    } 

} else {

    // user is not authenticated , perform rejection
}
```

Comment: Hello, how would you identify the user if he/she is not authenticated?

Comment: I answered in addition to the code snippet given by @sarah. After checking if the user is authenticated or not (as in the code snippet), my answer can be implemented.